# seeing changes in shelve in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, shelve

I am using TFS 2010. I have to review code which is shelved by other developer before checkin. How can we do this in TFS2010 so that I can get his changes and review.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is:

- Press "Unshelve" on Pending Changes tab
- Find shelvest by typing "Owner Name" - the other developer tfs user name.
- Unshelve it.

[image]

Comment: View  => Other Windows => Pending Changes